# ag-grid: prorgamatically select next row from currently selected row

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid in an anugular1 project.

I'm trying to get the 'Next' button to select the next row in my grid.

```
$scope.NextButtonClick = function (){
    console.log("next button clicked");
    var selectedNodes = $scope.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes();
    var indexCurrentSelection = selectedNodes[0].childIndex;
```

I was hoping for a function like

```
    var nextNode = MagicalStoreOfallNodes.getNodeByIndex(indexCurrentSelection + 1);
    nextNode.setSelected(true, true)
```

But I can't find anything in the documentation https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-model/

Any help most appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `rowSelection:'single` (I guess your question wouldnt make sense if it was 'multiple'), you can do this:

```
$scope.nextRecord = function () {
    let selectedNodes = $scope.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes();
    if (selectedNodes && selectedNodes.length === 1) {
        let selectedNode = selectedNodes[0];
        $scope.gridOptions.api.forEachNode((node) => {
            if (node.childIndex === (selectedNode.childIndex + 1)) {
                node.setSelected(true);
                return;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

But please be aware that this is a simple version of this - if you're using filtering you may need to use other versions of the forEach, or if you're using grouping you may need to check if its a parent or not and act accordingly

Comment: It's not Work Properly!
because after you select nextElement for first time you have two selected element and therefore it will not work after that.
you should use node.setSelected(true,true); second true will deselect all selectedNodes and after select current node

Comment: Also we dont have childIndex anymore in latest versions. You sholud use rowIndex instead of that